# X server does not keep running

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, xinit, bspwm

since yesterday I run an issue with my GUI. I installed fresh arch Linux and I can not keep running bspwm-git, after login I get login console again. 
Here is my .xinitrc

```
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
    xrdb -merge $sysresources
fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -merge "$userresources"
fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi

exec bspwm
```

Here is my .xserverrc

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/bin/Xorg/ -nolisten tcp -nolisten local "$@" vt$XDG_VTNR
```

My .zprofile is now like this

```
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ "$XDG_VTNR" -le 2 ]; then
    exec startx —- -keeptty 
fi
```

And w/o option -keeptty x server shuts down right after login

Kernel parameters

```
title   Arch Linux (linux)
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /intel-ucode.img
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options cryptdevice=PARTUUID=4df4ad4e-79d0-46ec-8097-4644fa3a43f6:root root=/dev/mapper/root rw rootfstype=btrfs nvidia_drm.modeset=1 nvidia_drm.fbdev=1
```

Comment: `Here is my ....` no, put that directly in the question, not in an external link

Comment: It is done, can you help me?

Comment: Are you running SystemD or init?